# SharePoint Online Multiple Sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, site

I've just published a SharePoint Site and it seems there's not just one, but many:

```
URL                                                STORAGE USED (GB)    SERVER RESOURCE QUOTA

https://example.sharepoint.com                            0.00              300
https://example.sharepoint.com/portals/hub                0.00              0
https://example.sharepoint.com/search                     0.03              0
https://example-my.sharepoint.com                         0.00              0
```

The question is why are there so many instead of one? If I need to delete it, will I have to delete all? Also, the last one seems strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find in the link below what are those site collections in SharePoint Online :

https://sharepointmaven.com/site-collections-sharepoint/